# Does GitHub notify owners if a member publicizes their organization?

Tags: github

https://help.github.com/articles/publicizing-or-hiding-organization-membership/

Just wondering if GitHub notifies anyone if a member makes their organization membership public?

Comment: Do you mean, if GitHub notifies the organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

I've tried this from both sides, being a member of an organization and also being part of an organization. I didn't get any notifications.